# javascript: setInterval execute with out stoping

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension and I need to use an interval.

The time the interval will go off every time is chosen by the user itself.

The function executes on every open tab and sends data to it.

My problem is that the "timer" dosn't work like it should, it just execute all at once like a normal while loop.

Here is the code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
//the times the code need to run is by the amount of tabs that is open
        setInterval(function () {
            if (i < tabs.length) {

                chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabs[i].id, { input: "uCanSend",

                    userName: myName,
                    password: myPass,

                    subject: mySubject, msg: myMsg,

                    linkName1: myLinkName1,
                    linkURL1: myLinkURL1,

                    linkName2: myLinkName2,
                    linkURL2: myLinkURL2

                }, function (response) { });

            }
            i++;
        }, timeInMintus //the time that the code need to run every time);
    });
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong.
Any idea how to fix it that it will run correctly?

(sorry for my English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument needs to be in milliseconds (thousandths of a second). Based on the variable name, it looks like you're passing minutes. For example, if you want the callback to run every minute:

```
setInterval(function () { /* snip */ }, 1000*60);
```

Comment: i ask the user to enter a number and i do chossenTime * 1000 and pess it then to timeInMintus

Comment: So what value is `timeInMintus`?

Comment: timeInMintus = choosenTime * 1000

Comment: Okay, so what value is `choosenTime`?

Comment: what the user chooses it can be 1,2,3,0.5

Comment: lol i checked it agian i was doing somthing, and i deleted the * 1000 part. thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome queues up setTimeout/setInterval calls on inactive tabs and changes the [minimal timeout length](http://codereview.chromium.org/6577021).

Comment: but i run this code from the background page to the tabs(content script)